# Como ocultar duas DIVs uma dentro da outra com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

estou enfrentando um problema ao tentar ocultar duas DIV´s, ou seja, uma dentro da outra. Apenas consigo ocultar uma DIV a outra fica visível.

Segue o que estou utilizando:

**Java Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function superpopgv(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup) {

    if(document.getElementById(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup).style.display=="none") {
        document.getElementById(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup).style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById(guaraparivirtualsuperpopup).style.display = "none";
    }

}
</script>
```

**CSS:**

```
#guaraparivirtualsuperpopup {
    position:relative;
    width:1215px;
    height:500px;
    background-color:#000000;
    /* background-image:url(http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br/Lay_Out/dr-bruno.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:50% 50%;
    */
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 9;
    border: 1px solid #EA8419;
}
#guaraparivirtualsuperpopupbtn {
    width:100px;
    height:36px;
    background-image:url(http://www.guaraparivirtual.com.br/img-novo/fechar.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    float:right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;  
}
```

**DIV´s**

```
<div class="guaraparivirtual-topo-100-barra-inferior">

<a href="#" onclick="javascript: superpopgv('guaraparivirtualsuperpopup');" >
<div id="guaraparivirtualsuperpopupbtn"></div>
</a>

<a href="<?php echo $linkbannerrt; ?>" target="_blank" title="Super Pop-Up" / >
<div id="guaraparivirtualsuperpopup" style="background-image:url(superpopup/<?php echo $rt; ?>);"></div>
</a>

</div>
```

Comment: Não conseguir entender muito o exemplo mas a dica que eu lhe dou é que se você ocultar a <div> pai certamente você vai esconder a filha, pode passar mais informações para te ajudar ??

Answer (score 0):

Obs: `getComputedStyle(el)` vai retornar os estilos atuais do elemento, o que torna melhor de obter o `display` do elemento.

---

O problema é porque você está declarando `"#guaraparivirtualsuperpopupbtn"` e + elementos fora da div `"#guaraparivirtualsuperpopup"`. Seu código precisa de uma nova estrutura para encaixar todos aqueles itens fora da `div` principal. Na verdade isso não é um problema, mas nada está acontecendo com os elementos fora da `div` principal. Sua `div` principal está sendo tratada como filha.